# Is there a way to keep an icon of each window separately on mac dock?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock

Is there a way (a software perhaps, a free software perhaps), that will allow me to keep several (the same) icons on mac dock instead of grouping all windows of one app into one icon?

For example I usually open many windows of Chrome and to operate between them I need to right-click on the chrome icon on my dock then select the window I want to pull up. I want to have as many chrome icons in dock as separate chrome windows are open.

I'm struggling with this issue from months, please help!

Comment: In case you do not really need to ungroup them (I understand you want to change windows in a convenient way) on Windows you probably use `Alt + Tab` which works fine - for example switching between many windows. On mac you can have the same functionality with using https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch
All you need is just to override `Cmd + Tab` and you will be able to jump from one Chrome window into another with a speed of light ;)

Comment: any good solutions as of today? it is very ineffective using multiple windows in 1 app in mac.

Answer (score 7):

I am currently using a software called uBar. It's a sort of Windows-type bar on the bottom, where every each of windows is kept as a separate icon. Here is the link to the actual software: [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar) and here is the link to the screenshot: [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/49v60al5p/). uBar has many options, but I really like dock and I would like to stick with it and get rid of uBar.

Answer (score 6):

What you can is minimize each window and the will show up in the right side of the doc then you click on the instance there or you can use exposé by default the shortcut is option + arrow down at the same time which will split out all the windows so you can choose which one you want. You can also use exposé on conjunction with minimizing the windows

Comment: Thank you, I thought that this answer may come up. I know what you mean but this is not a solution, as usually I don't minimize windows, it's a matter of habit. Too many years of using MS Windows :(

Comment: what about using exposé  ? I think that these are the only two options.

Comment: I am trying to limit the number of actions to one click. I work quite a lot on Internet and graphics and I'm not very patient :) So one click option is a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Two options - neither perfect, but using no additional software…

1. Use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>~</kbd>  &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>    <kbd>~</kbd>  to cycle through open windows in an app.
2. Manually lift each open window to its own Space - hold the title bar & use the  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>*number*</kbd>  to set which Space [will need setting up each time you use this method, it won't stick] then use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>*number*</kbd>  to go directly to each Space
   Key Commands for Spaces need to be set up first - System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control
   Each time you add a Space, the key command appears for it - 'Switch to Desktop *n*' - but must be manually switched on, at first use.
   *& yes, I really do wish they'd stop referring to Spaces as Desktops*

Personally, I use the Spaces option all the time. I have 2 monitors & 6 spaces, so 12 'desktops' lets me put pretty much everything in a space of its own, with single key switching.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin, it's a kind of solution but still not solving the issue. I know it's very useful, but too many years of using MS Windows affected my habits. I want to take a look on the Dock and see how many e.g. Chrome windows are currently open and using one click of mouse navigate between them.

Comment: I was aware it wasn't an ideal solution - but tbh, once you learn where each is, it's faster than clicking. The downside, in your case, is that one app wants to live in one Space, which will make the repeated manual setup somewhat irritating.

Comment: Alternatively - would using tabs instead of separate windows help?

Comment: I use multiple workspaces already, but I do many things in the same time and I want to see how many windows do I currently have. I will need to find a software which does that I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! I just figured it out. This has been driving me nuts on my Mac at home too. I just found your post while researching it. My Mac at work treated different Chrome windows separately in the dock so I knew there had to be a way.

Go to System Preference under Dock, uncheck 'Minimize windows into application icons'.

Comment: this doesn't help. I don't usually minimize windows. I need this to be working without minimizing them.

Comment: I will upvote because this is the most close you can get without install any third app.

Answer (score 0):

I use DragThing and then create a Window Dock along the bottom which sort of mimics the Windows style taskbar.

There is a post here on how to set it up: http://www.iwebss.com/tech/361-pc-style-windows-taskbar-on-mac-os-x

The only negative is that you can no longer move osx dock to the bottom right corner, so now it stays in the middle along the bottom so depending how many windows you have open, the dock will cover some of them up.

But it mostly gives you one click to jump between windows.